# Given two rationals $s,p$, do they exist three rationals whose sum is $s$ and product is $p$?

Tags: number-theory, rational-numbers

I found that

> Given two real numbers $s,p$, there exist three real numbers $x,y,z$ such that $x+y+z=s$ and $xyz=p$.

This is easy to prove when $p=0$: pick $x=s$ and $y=z=0$.

To prove the case $p \neq 0$, I consider $z \neq 0$ as a parameter in the quadratic equation
$$X^2-(s-z)X+\frac{p}{z}=0$$

The discriminant equals
$$\Delta = (s-z)^2 - \frac{4p}{z} \to + \infty$$ as $z \to + \infty$. Thus, for $z$ large enough $\Delta >0$, so that the quadratic equation has two solutions $x,y$ satisfying
$$x+y = s-z \ \ ; \ \ xy= \frac{p}{z}$$
as we wanted to prove.

Now, my question is:

> if $s,p$ are rational, can we find *rational* $x,y,z$ such that $x+y+z=s$ and $xyz=p$?

This relies on finding $z \in \Bbb{Q}^*$ such that $\Delta = (s-z)^2 - \frac{4p}{z}$ is the square of a rational number. However, here I got stuck.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no triple of rationals such that $x+y+z=1$ and $xyz=1$. I can prove that (by lots of computation), if $\frac{a}b=xy+yz+zx$, then $3^7=2187$ divides $b$, which makes me think there's probably not a solution.