# Non trivial solutions for the diophantine $X^2Y+XY^2+XYZ-Z^3=0$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, diophantine-equations, rational-numbers

This question comes from a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2691172/given-two-rationals-s-p-do-they-exist-three-rationals-whose-sum-is-s-and-pr) of mine.

I am trying to prove that the equation
$$xy(x+y+1)=1$$
has no rational solutions. (Such a solution would give three numbers, namely $-x, -y, 1-x-y$, whose sum and product are equal to $1$).

This can be thought as a homogeneous equation over the integers
$$XY(X+Y+Z)=Z^3$$
or equivalently $$X^2Y+XY^2+XYZ-Z^3=0$$
where $x= X/Z$ and $y=Y/Z$.

Clearly there are some trivial solutions for $Z=0$, but those are not interesting for my purposes.

So the question is

> Does $$X^2Y+XY^2+XYZ-Z^3=0$$ have non-trivial integer solutions ($Z \neq 0$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how elementary you wish the proof to be.

Using elliptic curves it is straightforward. $xy(x+y+1)=1$ give the quadratic in $x$, $y x^2+(y^2+y)x-1=0$. For rational $x$, the discriminant must be a rational square, so there must exist rational $D,y$ such that
\begin{equation*}
D^2=y^4+2y^3+y^2+4y
\end{equation*}

This can be transformed to the elliptic curve
\begin{equation*}
v^2=u^3+(u+4)^2
\end{equation*}
with
\begin{equation*}
y=\frac{v-u-4}{2u}
\end{equation*}

The elliptic curve has the points of order $3$ at $(0,\pm 4)$, and no others.
It has rank $0$ according to Simon's ellrank code.

There are thus NO rational points on the curve which give a point on the quadratic.

I cannot believe I am the first person to do this !!

Comment: I was there until I got stuck at $D^2=y^4+2y^3+y^2+4y$, since I don't know elliptic curves. Anyway, thanks for your answer, I will accept it in a while, if no other simpler answer appears.

Comment: That part is not hard: It's just the bit under the radical in the quadratic formula when you write it as a quadratic in $x$.